# Computer randomly turning off

Tags: desktop-computer

I just got a Msi 4gb Gtx 960 and now my computer randomly reboots
My computer has EVGA 100-W1-500-KR 500W ATX12V / EPS12V 80 PLUS Certified Active PFC Continuous Power Supply

Msi h110m gaming motherboard

G.SKILL Ripjaws 4 Series 16GB (2 x 8GB) 288-Pin DDR4 SDRAM DDR4 2133 (PC4 17000) Memory Kit Model

Intel Core i5-6500 6M Skylake Quad-Core 3.2 GHz LGA 1151 65W BX80662I56500 Desktop Processor

A 72000 wd 1tb hard drive

DEEPCOOL Gamer Storm CAPTAIN 120 CPU Liquid Cooler AIO Water Cooling Ceramic Bearing Pump Visual Liquid Flow with 120mm FDB PWM Fan Rubber Coating Deep Silent Support LGA 2011-v3

And the graphics card

Why is it powering off

Comment: A 500W PSU for a GTX 960 is a little light.  The recomended PSU is 400 W, your PSU has a maxmium load of around 475 W, which means that provies very little room for any other device.  You also have a very power hungry CPU and after market cooler.  This is a power supply problem upgrade it to 700W+ PSU or downgrade the GPU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Ramhound said in the comments, your issue likely stems from your power supply not having the juice to supply the whole system.

CoolerMaster even has a calculator you can use to determine what you need from your power supply to run your system smoothly. http://www.coolermaster.com/power-supply-calculator/

See this site's chart as a reference to the power consumption of your video card:

http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/nvidia-geforce-gtx-960,4038-8.html

700 watts is a good number to aim for when buying a new power supply, and 80+ ratings are definitely worth the few extra bucks.

If you intend to add more components to your computer in the future you may consider going even larger (800-1000W). This could be another graphics card (which will double the power consumption seen on the tomshardware page), more hard drives, etc.